# Multiple targets in the same project - but not lite vs. full

Tags: ios, xcode

There are two parts to my question:

1. Can I do this?
2. Should I do this?

I know that I can duplicate a target in Xcode, go through the necessary renaming, etc to have additional targets in my project.  When I search on others doing this, I see mostly the idea of building a "lite" version of the app.  This implies to me that it is for a situation where only one of the targets will be installed on a device at once.

What I have in mind is building a tool used for testing.  It is designed to work with my main app, launching it via a URL scheme.  So, I will have a main target "MyApp" and another target called "MyAppTester" or something like that.

If I have both of these apps in the same project, I should be able to build two separate IPA files via two separate schemes.  But will I have any trouble installing both of them side-by-side on the same device?  I'm wondering if they will wind up sharing something like an AppId that will get in my way.

The alternative is that I create a separate project (this is what I'm doing now).  There is a small amount of code that will be duplicated (not doing static libraries because of categories).

I'd appreciate any insight from anybody that has done something like this before.

Comment: Setup each target with its own Info.plist and app id. Just like you would for full/lite app pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only matter of preference and common sense. You'll set up individual parameters for each target, they might be completely unique including info.plist file and bundle identifier. Some preferences might be easily shared between targets through "project level" preferences values.

You don't need to copy and rename the existing targets, File > New menu has an option to create the new target that will come pre-configured. Copying is only useful if you want to retain some preferences that would take much time to copy, that is if you need it copied anyway. A well maintained project doesn't have implementation files just lying around - some built and some not - so it should be easy to add the required files. I guess copying a target might be good, but only when you have a big mess of the project.

The build dependencies can be established across targets of different projects in the same way as if the other target was a static library target. The good thing about having two targets at the same project in your case is that it is easier to launch the other from the one you are running as you can build the path easier, that's about it I think.